# Prevent lighter button colour after click

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

**How to prevent button text changing to a lighter/transparent/opaque after clicking?**

I have a button that I set to red, but after clicking it, the button colour turns a bit whiteish. Is there anyway to prevent this happening?

**Header Toolbar with button (myPage.ts)**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    
    <ion-buttons>
      <ion-button style="color: red;">
        <ion-label>Done</ion-label>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I need the buttons to remade solid red whether it's clicked on or not.

I'm not exactly sure if this is an ionic or angular problem, since all links change colour after clicking them.

**Edit**

Changing the background does not stop the colour fading out, nor does it seem like focus/active/visited styles change anything

[image: Proper button colour]

[image: Faded button]

Interestingly, when I click away from the button, it goes back to full colour

(Ionic 5, Angular 9)

Comment: Did my answer help you? Despite the downvote I think it's exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @Helsing Unfortunately it didn't :( focus/active/visited styles changes nothing

Comment: It's hard to say then, but try doing !important just to see if your rule is actually being matched or not. If !important works, it just means the rule was being overriden. In this case you would have to make the rule more specific. Try a:visited {
  color: red !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a style tag. you can use simple ion-button style form [Ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button).

go to the scss file and add style

```
ion-button{
    --background-activated: var(--ion-color-danger);
}
```

you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the background of It.

```
button{background: tomato}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to change this with CSS.

There is a pseudo class called visited:

```
a:visited {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is further reading about styling links:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp